# Can't install any GNOME extension with Vivaldi browser on Debian

Tags: debian, chrome

To have GNOME Shell Extensions installed within Vivaldi browser in Fedora 28 I needed to install `chrome-gnome-shell` and it worked without problems. Now when I switched to Debian Testing, I cannot get it working.

When on [GNOME Shell extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org) site, it shows:

> **Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector
>   is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector.** My Vivaldi is a current one [Vivaldi 1.15.1147.64 (Stable channel) (64-bit)].

I can't install any GNOME extension because of it. I reinstalled `chrome-gnome-shell` but it didn't help.

Comment: Being in Debian testing sometimes breaks stuff.

Comment: I moved back from Fedora because it breaks stuff even more.